# Master theorem not applicable?

Tags: proof-techniques, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Given the following recursive equation

$$ T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+n\log n$$ we want to apply the Master theorem and note that

$$ n^{\log_2(2)} = n.$$

Now we check the first two cases for $\varepsilon > 0$, that is whether

- $n\log n \in O(n^{1-\varepsilon})$ or
- $n\log n \in \Theta(n)$.

The two cases are not satisfied. So we have to check the third case, that is whether

- $n\log n \in \Omega(n^{1+\varepsilon})$ .

I think the third condition is not satisfied either. But why? And what would be a good explanation for why the Master theorem cannot be applied in this case?

Comment: See [case 2 generic form in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form_3).

Comment: Case three is not satisfied because $\log n$ is not $\Omega(n^\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. Use l'Hôpital's rule on the limit $\frac{\log n}{n^{\epsilon}}$

Comment: Once you show that neither case applies, that is *proof* that you can not apply the master theorem as stated.

Comment: Who needs the Master Theorem?  Use recursion trees.

Comment: [Similar question on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/159720/3330).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The three cases of the Master Theorem that you refer to are proved in the *Introduction to Algorithms* by Thomas H. Cormen,Charles E. Leiserson,Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein (2nd Edition, 2001).

It is correctly observed that the recurrence in question falls between Case 2 and Case 3. That is $f(n) = n \log n$ grows faster than $n$ but slower than $n^{1+\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

However the theorem can be generalized to cover this recurrence. Consider

**Case 2A:**
Consider $f(n) = \Theta (n^{\log_b a }\log_b^k n)$ for some $k\geq 0$.

This case reduces to Case 2 when $k = 0$. It is intuitively clear that along each branch of the recurrence tree $f(x)$ is being added $\Theta (\log_b n)$ times. A sketch of a more formal proof can be found below. The final result is that

$$T(n) = \Theta (n^{\log_b a }\log_b^{k+1} n).$$

In the *Introduction to algorithms* this statement is left as an exercise.

Applying this statement to the recurrence in question we finally get

$$
    T(n) = \Theta(n \cdot \log^2 n).
$$

More details on the Master Theorem can be found in the excellent (imho) [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2).

As @sdcvvc points in the comments to prove that Case 3 does not apply here one can invoke L'Hospital's rule that says that

$$
   \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f^\prime(x)}{g^\prime(x)}
$$

for any functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ differentiable in the vicinity of $c$. Applying this to $f(n) = n \log n$ and $g(n) = n^{1+\varepsilon}$ one can show that $\log n \not\in \Theta (n^{1+\varepsilon}).$

---

Sketch of the Proof of the Master Theorem for Case 2A.

This is a reproduction of parts of the proof from *Introduction to Algorithms with the necessary modifications*.

First we prove the following Lemma.

**Lemma A:**

Consider a function

$$
 g(n) = \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{\log_b {n-1}} a^j h(n/b^j)
$$

where $h(n) = n^{\log_b a} \log_b^k n.$ Then
$g(n) = n^{\log_b a} \log_b^{k +1} n.$

**Proof:**
Substituting the $h(n)$ into the expression for $g(n)$ one can get
$$g(n) = \displaystyle n^{\log_b a} \log_b^k n \; \sum_{j=0}^{\log_b{n-1}}  \left(\frac{a}{b^{\log_b a}}\right)^j = n^{\log_b a} \log_b^{k +1} n.$$

**QED**

If $n$ is an exact power of $b$ given a recurrence

$$
 T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n),\quad  T(1) = \Theta(1)
$$

one can rewrite it as

$$
 T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a}) + \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{\log_b n - 1} a^j f(n/b^j).
$$

Substituting $f(n)$ with $\Theta(n^{\log_b a} \log_b^k n)$, moving $\Theta$ outside and applying Lemma A we get

$$T(n) = \Theta (n^{\log_b a }\log_b^{k+1} n).$$

Generalizing this to an arbitrary integer $n$ that is not a power of $b$ is beyond the scope of this post.

Answer (score 1):

The Akra-Bazzi theorem is a strict generalization of the master theorem. As a bonus its proof is a blizzard of integrals that will make your head spin ;-)

In any case, Sedgewick in his ["Introduction to the analysis of algorithms"](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/home) argues convincingly that one should strive to prove $T(n) \sim g(n)$ type asymptotics.