# Explanation of a specific recurrence with respect to Master Theorem

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Concerning the Master Theorem. I have found the following equation as the base of analysis:

$\quad T(n) = aT(n/b) + \Theta(n^k)$

but I also found the following:

$\quad T(n) = aT(n/b) + \Theta(n^k\cdot\log_p n)$

where the base $p$ is a real number.

Can anyone explain the second equation? I understand the proof with the first equation but can not understand the second formula.

Comment: Your question is not clear? Where do you have "found" the formulas? What proof?

Comment: They are from text-books.By proof I mean how to extract the 3 branches that specify the complexities in Master Theorem

Comment: Could be related to [another similar question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1957/1185).

Comment: @DmitriChubarov:I see that you use similar notation in your answer but my question is where the `log` comes from in the second formula

Comment: If you look up the wikipedia article you could see that the generic form of the [second branch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form_3) is $f(n) = \Theta \left(n^{\mathop{\text{log}}{}_b a} \mathop{\text{log}}{}^k n \right)$ that matches both formulas in your question.

Comment: Without the algorithm being analysed we won't be able to tell you where the $\log$ comes from.

Comment: There no algorithm.It is from presentation on the master theorem

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the master theorem is only given for recursions of the form $T(n) = aT(n/b) + \Theta(n^k)$, but the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) includes a more general version which can handle functions of the form $T(n) = aT(n/b) + \Theta(n^k(\log n)^l)$, and even more general ones when $k \neq \log_b a$. The similar [Akra-Bazzi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra-Bazzi_method) handles more general situations.